# SelectList selected default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I have this in my Controller:

```
ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ID", "Name");
```

This in my View (using razor)

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",})
```

When I load my view I have the first client selected by default and I want to have "--Select Client--"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this [overload of Html.DropDownList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492256%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to add option label:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientID", 
                   null,
                   "Select Client", 
                   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

if you want to set SelectedValue from database then set it in `SelectList()` constructor as @Nadeem Khan posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following manner.Please look at the below mentioned answer

```
 ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ID", "--Select Client--", selectedValue);
```

Let me know if it helped you. 
Thanks

Comment: OP explicitly asked how to do it in ASP .NET MVC. Telling them to "Search the same thing in MVC" is not an answer. They have searched by coming here... Could you please revise answer to include an MVC snippet.

Comment: @Belogix: I edited my answer. There was no need of downvote. Though let it

Comment: Removed downvote as you have now at least provided some MVC snippet, thank you.

Comment: Its not working. It says that selectedValue does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view:-

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientID",null,"--Select Client--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",})
```

You need to use this overloaded version of [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329(v=vs.118).aspx).