# SelectList Default Value don't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

today I'm having trouble with Default Value for a SelectList in ASP.NET.

here is how I do after trying lots of things I found in the Internet:

```
@{
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> secteurSelectList = from x in Model.secteurList select new SelectListItem {
                                       Selected = (x.Id == this.GetSessionSecteurId()),
                                       Text = x.Secteur,
                                       Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                   };
  SelectList selectList = new SelectList(secteurSelectList, "Value", "Text", secteurSelectList.Where(x => x.Selected==true).FirstOrDefault().Value); }
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.secteur, selectList)
```

Here is the description of My entities:
In the ViewModel I use

```
public List<AuditSecteur> secteurList { get; set; }
```

Here is the AuditSecteur's object:

```
public class AuditSecteur
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Secteur { get; set; }
}
```

This is the result:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Secteur de l'audit must be a number." data-val-required="The Secteur de l'audit field is required." id="secteur" name="secteur">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

SecteurSelectedList has one item at true for the selected:
[image: one item selected]
SelectedList too:
[image: one item seledted too]

Thanks to help me

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777478/selectlist-selected-default-value

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for your response, but I don't want to add one element but just pre-select (dynamycally) the item for the user (to avoid that the user will always (90% of the time) select the same). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of using the strongly typed helpers is to **bind** your model properties so in the case of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.secteur, selectList)
```

if the value of `secteur` does not match the value of one of your options, then it wont be selected (actually because it cant find a match, the first option will be selected because something needs to be selected).

But there are numerous other issues with your code. First you creating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (setting the `Selected` property is pointless since its ignored by the helper), then you create another `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (the `SelectList`) based on the first one in the next line (whats the point?). The value of the options generated are based on the `ID` property of `AuditSecteur` but then you bind to to the `Secteur` property so it would never post back a correct value anyway. Its not really clear how your using this (you have not included you model, controllers or view) but the correct approach would be something like

View model

```
public class SecteurVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Secteur")]
  [Required]
  public int? SelectedSecteur { get; set; }
  public SelectList SecteurList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  List<AuditSecteur> secteurList = // get AuditSecteur items from the database
  SecteurVM model = new SecteurVM();
  model.SecteurList = new SelectList(secteurList, "ID", "Secteur");
  model.SelectedSecteur = // set the default value you want selected here
  return View(model)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SecteurVM model)
{
  // model.SelectedSecteur contains the ID of the selected item
}
```

View

```
@model SecteurVM
....
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSecteur)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSecteur, Model.SecteurList, "--Please select--")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSecteur)
```

If the value of `SelectedSecteur` matches one of the `ID` properties of the items in the list, then that is the option that will be selected when you display the view.

Comment: Yes I did those mistakes because I've tried lots of example sin the Internet, and I tried all thinks that indicated the Defaulkt in fact :-) Your method is the best, I wanted to compute the selectedIteml in the view but in the ViewModel is better after all.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you're binding DropDown to `secteur` property of the Model while Value propety of the dropdown is `Id` so dropdown won't find the corresponding value while making pre-selection.

here even if you have defined `pre-selected` item it will `reset` while rendering, so i would suggest bind you dropdown to `Id` instead of `secteur`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, selectList)
```